# Angular 1.4.1 UI Router 10 $digest() iterations when $state.go called on $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state that requires authorization. I listen to the `$stateChangeStart` event and if the `toState.data.protected`and the user is not authorized I call `e.preventDefault()` and `$state.go('login')`.

When I open the app in root url I'm automatically redirected to protected state.
This causes 10 $digest loops and I end up in the login state when I open the app in the root url and I'm automatically redirected to a protected state.

`Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

See this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/1voh7m?p=preview

I successfully use similar code in different project with angular 1.2.26 with no errors.

Example code  `angular 1.4.1, ui.router 0.2.15`:

```
//config block
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');   
$stateProvider
 .state('main', {
   url: '/main',
     templateUrl: 'main.html',
     controller: 'MainController as main',
     data: {'protected': true}
 }) 
 .state('login', {
     url: '/login',
     templateUrl: 'login.html',
     controller: 'LoginController as login'
 });

// in a run block
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState) {
    if (!event.defaultPrevented && toState.data &&
            toState.data.protected) {
        // the user is not authorized, do not switch to state
        event.preventDefault();
        // go to login page
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

Do you know what causes the loop?

I wonder if the things might be happening like this:

1. Intercept the transition to main.submain state
2. Start transition to login state
3. UI router gets the information that the first transiotion got cancelled
4. UI router runs `$urlRouter.update()` and starts transition to main.submain

**EDIT:** Simplified state configuration.

Comment: Where are you defining what data is protected?

Comment: Using the state definition: `data: {'protected': true}` on the main state. The state are prototypically inherited so the main.submain state has the same value.

Comment: I apologize I had an incorrect plunk attached which didn't demonstrate the issue.

Comment: if i not mistaken, you should not use _$urlRouterProvider_ with one `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main'); ` branch, because for any other url it try redirect to _'main'_ and you in infinite loop, i have a bit change your plunker try check it: http://plnkr.co/edit/RyWEusonoBhfQjwD32uu?p=preview

Comment: @Grundy Thx. I just came here to post an answer to similar solution. I believe you should be able to use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');` with my solution - because you just want to have some default redirection. I like your plunk and I will post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an issue of the UI.Router – see this issue on Github: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/600

Basically, if you use `.otherwise('/main')` (also pointed out by @Grundy) then the url is changed to `/main` when the path cannot be resolved. After `$locationChangeSuccess` my listener is called and I reject the redirection using `event.preventDefault()`. This causes the location to change back to the unknown path thus causing the fallback path to be used again. This causes the infinite loop. The solution is this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
  var $state = $injector.get('$state');
  $state.go('main');
});
```

You can state a function which gets called with `$injector` and you can redirect to your main state (or 404) without back-and-forth location changes. Thx to the guys on Github, I should have searched there before posting this question.

Working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/eQXaIk

Comment: Helped, Thanks a ton!